# .NET Core MVC - Save time spent on a task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to save time spent on a task by two categories: *Break* and *Work*.
I can't use JS for this. I am working with ASP.NET Core 2 MVC.
I have a solution but there's probably a better one.

**My solution** is to create *Work* and *Break* buttons in "/Task/Details/{id}" view.

- When user clicks *Work* button, it creates a record in DB (model below)
  where `DateTime Start` equals current time.
- When user clicks
  *Break* button, it finds last record in DB by `TaskID` from a view and saves current time in `DateTime End`.

Then I can select all `Time` records with specific `TaskID` and calculate the difference between `Start` and `End`.

```
public class Time
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int TaskID { get; set; } // Foreign key
  public string Category { get; set; };
  public DateTime Start { get; set; };
  public DateTime End { get; set; }

  public Task Task // Navigation property
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution with us. It has been fun :)

Comment: @CodingYoshi could you please share yours? :) What do you think?

Comment: My above comment was sort of a playful sarcastic one because you did not ask a question but just told us about your solution. Plus SO is not the place for such questions: it is more for helping with broken code or showing code and asking for an alternative. You are asking for a solution which is too broad. Try being more specific.

Comment: This is a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "I have a solution but there's probably a better one." is literally asking for an alternative.

Comment: Is your app used by multiple users?  How do you populate Category?

Comment: Each button equals category therefore _Work_ button is work category, automatically assigned when clicked.

Comment: Some considerations:
1. If you only need time difference, why not store that difference only? You'd need one column less. `TimeSpan` structure would probably fit. It will be zero on insertion and updated to positive number afterwards.

2. If you need both start and end times consider `DateTimeOffset` property type instead of `DateTime`.

3. I suppose it is better to rename class to `WorkInterval` or similar.

Comment: @Eugene `DateTimeOffset` indeed would be better. I rename class to `WorkInterval` also. But I don't understand how would I know how much time passed if I wanted to update the zero insertion value?

Comment: @RubyHarris I though you could keep start time somewhere in outer scope. You can't, so using two columns is reasonable. Another approach with single column is to store UNIX time stamp there. On insertion store UNIX time stamp of current date and time, on update replace that value with difference of current and stored time stamp.
Huge value - more than 1524949098 seconds - indicates that column contains initial datetime, small value - less than say 1 year in seconds - indicates that column contains interval duration.

Comment: @Eugene, that's the right answer, it's the insight I needed. Please post it so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you only need time difference, why not store that difference only? You'd need one column less. You can store [UNIX time stamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) there. On insertion store UNIX time stamp of current date and time, on update replace that value with difference of current and stored time stamp. Huge value - more than 1524949098 seconds - indicates that column contains initial datetime, small value - less than say 1 year in seconds - indicates that column contains interval duration.
2. If you need both start and end times consider `DateTimeOffset` property type instead of `DateTime`.
3. I suppose it is better to rename class to `WorkInterval` or similar.